# Woocommerce products have duplicated links with different categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I think this is the first time I have such a situation.... Products that are in two different categories have two different URLs; and both are working just fine.

Ex.

```
https://example.com/cat1/sub-cat1/prod-name/
https://example.com/cat2/sub-cat2/prod-name/
```

Is there a way to block this? I thought that by specifying the scheme "/store/%product_cat%/" in the links settings, only the main category (set for the product) will be taken.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is looking at only the last segment in the URL, and finding the product with that slug. For example, this works:

https://zyjlatwiej.pl/this-does-not-exist/nor-does-this/and-neither-does-this/kubek-tasty/

There may be a way to prevent this from working, but I think it would significantly negatively impact site performance.

This behavior is why having a canonical tag set on every page is important.

The only way I can see to accomplish blocking other URLs, would be to use the `template_redirect` action to analyze the request/URL, and then set the page to 404 if the URL doesn't match the preferred URL.

Comment: Is there a way to block it somehow or set a strict one url per product rule?